# Java MongoDb change a value in an array

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

I'm looking for a way to change the value of just 1 integer inside an array.
I don't want to get the whole array, change the value and put it back again because another thread can change the value of an integer.

```json
[
  {
    "row 1": [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "row 2": [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "row 3": [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "row 4": [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "row 5": [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "row 6": [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "row 7": [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "row 8": [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ]
  }
]
```

This is the "seats" document that is inside an "showInstance" document, and the "showInstance" document is inside an "show" document.

This is the show document

```json
{
  "_id": 1,
  "name": "Great rock show",
  "description": "The party will roll all night long during the North American WorldWired tour as we’re psyched to announce that award-winning DJ and producer Mix Master Mike will be spinning some of your favorite (and ours!) hard rock and metal tracks throughout the evening at all of the stadium dates this summer. A pioneer in the hip-hop and DJ communities, you’ll be able to catch his skillful, hard-hitting scratch work once the doors open each night and between acts before we hit the stage.",
  "band_id": 3,
  "instances": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "58cea4779f3489310471b7db"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2017-04-07T15:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "price": 140,
      "theater_id": 3,
      "seats": [
        {
          "row 1": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 2": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 3": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 4": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 5": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 6": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 7": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 8": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "58cea4779f3489310471b7dc"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2017-05-04T15:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "price": 758,
      "theater_id": 5,
      "seats": [
        {
          "row 1": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 2": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 3": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 4": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 5": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 6": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 7": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 8": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 9": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 10": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "58cea4779f3489310471b7dd"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2017-05-23T15:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "price": 634,
      "theater_id": 9,
      "seats": [
        {
          "row 1": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 2": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 3": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 4": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "58cea4779f3489310471b7de"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2017-06-02T15:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "price": 398,
      "theater_id": 3,
      "seats": [
        {
          "row 1": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 2": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 3": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 4": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 5": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 6": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 7": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 8": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "58cea4779f3489310471b7df"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2017-06-29T15:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "price": 36,
      "theater_id": 9,
      "seats": [
        {
          "row 1": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 2": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 3": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 4": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "58cea4779f3489310471b7e0"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2017-08-08T15:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "price": 377,
      "theater_id": 11,
      "seats": [
        {
          "row 1": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 2": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 3": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 4": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 5": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 6": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 7": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 8": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 9": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 10": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "58cea4779f3489310471b7e1"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2017-08-28T15:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "price": 885,
      "theater_id": 12,
      "seats": [
        {
          "row 1": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 2": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 3": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 4": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 5": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 6": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 7": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 8": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 9": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 10": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 11": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 12": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "58cea4779f3489310471b7e2"
      },
      "date": {
        "$date": "2017-09-26T15:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "price": 853,
      "theater_id": 3,
      "seats": [
        {
          "row 1": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 2": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 3": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 4": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 5": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 6": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 7": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "row 8": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: are you updating the whole `row` array element in the `seats` array ?

Comment: No, what i want to do is to update a single element in a row

Comment: What is the criteria to determine which `row` and which element in that `row` to update after you have identify the `seats` array ?

Comment: it a request coming from the server, I just need to figure out how to make that query.

Comment: @Yuval Is it necessary to paste such a large amount of data into your question? It makes it quite difficult to read, compared to a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @VinceBowdren tnx  mate  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the element position, you can use it to update the value, e.g.

```
BasicDBObject setQuery = new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject("instances.$.seats.0.row 1.0", 1));
collection.update(someSearchQuery, setQuery);
```

**Update**

Here's an example for query and update:

```
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("shows");
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id", 1);
query.put("instances._id", new ObjectId("58cea4779f3489310471b7db"));

BasicDBObject setQuery = new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject("instances.$.seats.0.row 1.0", 1));
collection.update(query, setQuery);
```

**Mongo query**

```
db.seats.update({"_id":1,"instances._id": ObjectId("58cea4779f3489310471b7db")}, {$set : {"instances.$.seats.0.row 1.0" : 100}})
```

The above query should update the "row 1" element to 100, I have updated the java exaple as well.

Comment: Hi Darshan, and thank you for the quick reply.
I'm kinda new to mongoDb and if I can get the full query it will be great:)
collection name =  "shows"
show id = 1
showInstanceId = "58cea4779f3489310471b7db"
and insinde the showInstance there is an array called ""seats"
Tnx

Comment: Yes, a show can have multiple instances, each instance has its own seat matrix

Comment: And another question, is this query only changes 1 cell? 
Or is it takes the object in line 1 and put it as a whole in line 2?
More precisely : what is being inserted to the DB? if a context switch occurred is there a chance of inconsistent data?

Comment: There won't be a chance of inconsistent data as mongodb doesn't support transactions at all. As far as `showInstance` is concerned, is it a `DBRef`?

Comment: its not a DBRef, the document showInstance is inside the show document

Comment: still no luck.
what to put in "someSearchQuery"?

Comment: still not a change

Comment: Updated the java example and added the query, seems to be working fine locally. Can you please have a look again?

Comment: OK, i ran it in the shell and it works(just changed from db.seats to db.shows)

Comment: the java code works as well !!!
thank you so much Darshan Mehta !!!
you are a king !!!